Does this prove $f = O(g) \iff f \cdot h = O(g\cdot h)$?
I wanted to know whether for any $3$ functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $g: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $h: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $f = O(g) \iff f \cdot h = O(g\cdot h)$.
This was my attempt at proving this: if $f = O(g)$, then $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{R} x> \delta \implies  f(x) \le c  \cdot g(x)$. If we let $x$ be any number belonging to $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: x> \delta\}$, then $f(x) \le c \cdot g(x)$, which implies that $f(x) \cdot h(x) \le c \cdot g(x) \cdot h(x)$; therefore, $\forall x \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: x> \delta\} f(x) \cdot h(x) \le c \cdot g(x) \cdot h(x)$, therefore $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{R} x> \delta \implies  f(x) \cdot h(x) \le c  \cdot g(x) \cdot h(x)$, therefore $f \cdot h = O(g\cdot h)$. This proves the forward direction of the claim we want to prove; the backwards direction can be proven by letting $f' = f \cdot h , g' = g \cdot h $, and $h' = 1/h$, and applying the foward direction to $f', g'$, and $h'$.
I am unsure of the above reasoning, in particular my use of generalizing a number in $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: x> \delta\}$ and extrapolating claims therefrom, as apparently if something is true of any given, explicit natural number, it doesn't mean it is true of any natural number, something about which I ask here.
So is this proof correct?

Your proof is correct. I do not understand your concern.
